# How can I use the min function in VBA to search a range and get the oldest date of a specific cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use the min and max function in VBA to get the newest and oldest date of each row of column "I". I get an error every time I run the code.

[image]
I'm trying to write a VBA code, using the min and max function, to search in column "B" where all the daily dates of all tickers are found, and get the oldest and newest date only of each ticker in column "I". Not sure why I'm getting an error, and not sure how to get the result I want. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Your VBA code is the equivalent of a worksheet function `=MIN("B")` which is meaningless. If you want to refer to a range, you need to use a range object. eg `Range("B:B")` or `Columns(2)` or various other methods. Research Range Objects in VBA and also methods to find the last row in this forum

Comment: Thanks Ron, I've already written a code to find the last row. I should add though that the date column is set to "general" in excel, do I need to change it to "number" in order for the Min and Max function to work? Thanks for your help as I am new to this.

Comment: Max/Min work fine with dates when cell format is General

Comment: The format is irrelevant. The functions work on the value stored in the cell. Formatting only changes how that value is displayed. Research how dates are stored for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws

    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Beg_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(.Range("B2:B" & LR))
    End_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(.Range("B2:B" & LR))
    Yearly...
    
End With
```

**However**, I note from your screenshot that the dates in question are probably not actually dates, but strings of text that look a little like dates. `Min` only works on numbers (dates are usually stored in Excel as numbers), so you either need to:

- Load Column B as dates/numbers on import
- Convert your column B to dates/numbers once imported.